# Finding the next select after an input field with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint

I have already have a handle to  an input field:

```
$("input[title = 'Start Date']");
```

I have 2 select fields after the input.

I need to be able to select both of those select fields separately. I tried `.next('select')` but that does not work because they are not siblings.

This is a Sharepoint make so it is very HTML heavy.   What I am really trying to do is to get a handle on the hours and minutes select control.

All 3 fields are in the same row.  Each in it's own `<td>`.   I really don't want to get into counting cells.  I would rather just select the first `<select>` and the second `<select>` after the input.

Is there any way to get those selects being they are not siblings of the input?

Comment: can you post the relevant html?

Comment: Any chance we could see the mark up?

Comment: something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ce4k9g2b/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to count cells. Here is how to get two `select` elements in the same row as an input even though they are in different cells:

```
var selects = $( 'select',  $('input[title="Start Date"]').closest('tr') );
```

Comment: Thanks both of the above ideas worked perfectly.  I should have mentioned I already know how to select the whole row.  One question.   Why must I use .value to get the value of each select?   .val()  does not work. selects[0].value works but not selects[0].val().  I can post as new question if needed.

Comment: .val() is a jquery method so you do have to wrap the element to access the method. Try $(selects[0]).val() instead.

Comment: Or `selects.first().val()`, or `selects.eq(0).val()`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.closest` and `.find` to find the elements.

```
$("input[title = 'Start Date']").closest('tr').find('select');
```